# Reading Java sockets - either receiving duplicate lines or loss

Tags: java, sockets

I am having a field day trying to figure out why my Java code is not working.

I am supposed to receive the following messages from a C program via sockets.

> 1~message~i love you\r\n
>   2~message~do you love me?\r\n 
>   3~message~when are we going to meet again?\r\n 
>   4~message~How about now?\r\n
>   5~message~Oh! I'm pregnant!\r\n

Instead, I am receiving the following messages instead.

> 1~message~i love you\r\n 
>   2~message~do you love me?\r\n 
>   2~message~do you love me?\r\n 
>   5~message~Oh! I'm pregnant!\r\n

I ran a port redirector on my laptop and found out that the C program is transmitting the messages correctly. It's my Java program that is not receiving them properly.

I am using Java NIO Channels to receive the messages.

My code as follows:

```
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
int pos = 0;     // position of Buffer

// initialize server and client sockets
ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = null;
SocketChannel clientChannel = null;

// initialize ByteBuffer
ByteBuffer inBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(65536);
inBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

try {
   serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
   SocketAddress port = new InetSocketAddress(8080);
   serverChannel.socket().bind(port);

      while (true) {
         clientChannel = serverChannel.accept();

         while ((bytesRead = clientChannel.read(inBuffer)) != -1) {

            inBuffer.flip();

               while (inBuffer.get(pos) != '\r') {

                  stringBuffer.append((char) inBuffer.get(pos));
                  pos++;

               } // end while loop checking for bytesRead

               //increment over \r and \n
               inBuffer.get();
               bytesRead--;
               inBuffer.get();
               bytesRead--;
               pos = pos + 2;

               System.out.println(stringBuffer);
               stringBuffer.setLength(0);
               pos = 0;

           } // close while reading bytesRead loop

      } // close while(true) loop
} catch (IOException ex) {
}
```

Comment: you don't appear to reset the inBuffer e.g. clear() it so you will just keep appending to it. Not sure why you maintain your own `pos` and `get(pos)` variable when using the builtin `position()` and `get()` is more natural.

Comment: You appear to expect only one line and ignore any additional lines.

Comment: I would suggest you use the plain InputStream first with BufferedInputStream as these are much simpler to use.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your feedback. I had tried once with InputStream and the end result was losing random messages. But I'll definitely recode one in InputStream and see how it goes from there. I wonder if the VM memory would have a bearing on how fast the Java app picks up incoming sockets.

Comment: I am trying to read in a bufferful of data first. Process this bufferful of data to move the message into a stringBuffer and upon reaching an \r, remove \r and \n. I think I need to relook my code too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try plain IO which is simpler for this use case.

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
while(!serverSocket.isClosed()) {
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("Accepted socket "+socket);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int b;
    while((b = bis.read())>=0) {
        if (b == '\r')
            b = bis.read();
        if (b == '\n') {
            System.out.println(sb);
            sb.setLength(0);
        } else {
            sb.append((char) b);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Closing socket.");
    socket.close();
}
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks again. One reason why i chose to use Channels was to send the message into a ByteBuffer which was set up for little endian reading. I had written near exact code to yours above but I am having trouble trying to convert a string to little endian (to sending back to the client) as part of the handshake. I am trying to avoid the use of external libraries to handle the endian-ness. In all, I can convert the received little endian message to big endian, but don't know how to convert from big endian message to little endian to send back to the client. As such i used a Bytebuffer.

Comment: I suggest you either send text with carriage returns as you have here OR you send binary data.  Text generally does need to worry abotu endianess as every character is encoded in a given order (with the exception of UTF-16/32 which I don't suggest you use)  If you have worry about endianess you have binary data and I would just use a binary format throughout.  Can you clarify, do you have text or binary or some hybrid format?

Comment: Hi Peter, I have text format and sending the data to the C program in bytes. Strange as it seems, I could not send text only to the C program. I had to do bit shifting from Java's Big Endian to Little Endian before the C program could respond with the handshake. And with everyone's help and yours especially, I have fixed my code and it now works. Further, I have added the code to a Runnable which makes it super sweet and fast!

Answer (score 1):

Do you *have* to use NIO for this? It's generally a lot harder to get right (at least for me). My guess is that the problem is that you're always reading, but you're calling `flip` exactly once per read... whereas I'd expect to see two flips, or possibly a flip before the `read` and then a `clear` at the end of the processing.

Note that you're also completely ignoring `bytesRead` - why bother decrementing a variable which you're then reassigning without reading?

Furthermore, you're assuming you get *exactly* one `\r` from each `read` call. What if you receive two lines in one call, or one imcomplete line?

I'm not qualified to give the correct NIO code, but I'd recommend that you try to get it working with a plain `InputStream` first and *then* move onto NIO.

Comment: Hi Jon, You're totally right about the use of NIO. I was trying out NIO and was just reusing the code. You're right about bytesRead too, extraneous. Regarding receiving the scenario of receiving one incomplete line, that's something I have yet to code in. But you're right in all counts.

Answer (score 0):

- SocketChannel.read puts data into the buffer *at the buffers current position*. You're iterating the buffer from *position 0* every time.
- If you get two lines in one `read` you're only handling up to the first \r and then continuing by reading again. You may miss the final lines this way.

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for your note. It dawned onto me that this is a scenario i have not expected - good stuff!